# Is there a way to get python's nose module to work the same in __main__ and on the command line?

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

I'm not sure of how to get the nose module's `__main__` handler to work. I have this at the end of my test module:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import nose
    nose.main()
```

Which gives me:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.002s

OK
```

but it I run the same thing via the command line, it finds the tests and executes them:

```
MacBook-Pro:Storage_t meloam$nosetests FileManager_t.py 
............E..
======================================================================
ERROR: testStageOutMgrWrapperRealCopy (WMCore_t.Storage_t.FileManager_t.TestFileManager)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

SNIP

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 15 tests in 0.082s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I've been playing with passing different arguments to nose.main() but I can't find anything that works. Am I missing something really obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For posterity's sake, this is what I use:

```python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import nose
    nose.run(argv=[__file__, '--with-doctest', '-vv'])
```

The `--with-doctests` will also execute your doctests in the same file.

Comment: Oddly, I can't just run this from Aquamacs.   Aquamacs doesn't set the __file__ variable for the temporary file into which it writes the buffer.

Comment: Giving nose the filename is smart. I was getting weird errors like it was trying to interpret the function it was in as a module name.

Comment: This seems functionally equivalent to `nose.runmodule(argv=[ 'nose', '--with-doctest', '-vv'])`

Answer (score 8):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import nose
    nose.run(defaultTest=__name__)
```

Answer (score 7):

[nose.runmodule](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/core.html#nose.core.runmodule) is the way to go:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import nose
    nose.runmodule()
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking 2 things:

Make sure your Source **FILES** follow the appropriate naming convention: (detailed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457104/nose-unable-to-find-tests-in-ubuntu/1457852#1457852)).

I, for instance, had to append "_Test" to all my source files. 
Then, all you need is this argument (assuming your main is at the root of the tests):

```
nose.main(defaultTest="")
```

I tried with:

```
nose.run(defaultTest=__name__)
```

as a previous answer suggested, but for some reason it wasnt working for me. I had to do BOTH things to get it working!

Hope it helps.

EDIT: 
By the way, calling with

```
 nose.run()
```

or

```
 nose.main()
```

made no discernible difference either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `nose.core.TestProgram` directly by passing it fake command line arguments. That I'm not sure though will if find your tests from the same module as you're using