# Run all Tests in Directory Using Nose

Tags: python, nose

I need to be able to run all tests in the current directory by typing one line in the Linux shell. In some directories, this works fine. But in others, when I type "nosetests" no tests are run. The tests will run if I call for them individually but I need them to all run automatically. Here is one of the directories that won't work:

```
/extwebserver
    __init__.py
    test_Detection.py
    test_Filesystem.py 
    test_Hardware.py
    ...
```

When I run "nosetests" in the parent directory, all tests in a certain subdirectory are run but no tests from /extwebserver or other subdirectories or the parent directory itself are run.

**EDIT**
Here's the output:

```
matthew@Matthew-Laptop:~/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing$ nosetests -vv --collect-only
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/baseTestCase.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/extwebserver/run.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/extwebserver/test_Detection.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/extwebserver/test_Filesystem.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/extwebserver/test_Hardware.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/extwebserver/test_Mode.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/extwebserver/test_System.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/extwebserver/test_View.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/extwebserver/test_Webserver.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/mocks/bottle.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/utils/test_timestamps.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/testCamera.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/testCameraManager.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/testMainControllerServer.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/testMode.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/testPASEServerClient.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/testView.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/testViewsManager.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/test_commission/test_FSM.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/matthew/Documents/ParkAssist/m3/linux/appfs/master/usr/bin/piopio/testing/test_commission/test_Webserver.py is executable; skipped
test_add (testing.utils.test_config.test_config) ... ok
test_add_set (testing.utils.test_config.test_config) ... ok
test_load (testing.utils.test_config.test_config) ... ok
test_load_valid (testing.utils.test_config.test_config) ... ok
test_modify_set (testing.utils.test_config.test_config) ... ok
test_save (testing.utils.test_config.test_config) ... ok
test_update (testing.utils.test_config.test_config) ... ok
test_get_full_version (testing.utils.test_controller.test_controller) ... ok
test_get_hwaddr (testing.utils.test_controller.test_controller) ... ok
test_get_ip (testing.utils.test_controller.test_controller) ... ok
test_get_netmask (testing.utils.test_controller.test_controller) ... ok
test_get_version (testing.utils.test_controller.test_controller) ... ok
test_FloatEncoder (testing.utils.test_fileio.test_fileio) ... ok
test_read_file (testing.utils.test_fileio.test_fileio) ... ok
test_read_json_string (testing.utils.test_fileio.test_fileio) ... ok
test_system_to_text (testing.utils.test_fileio.test_fileio) ... ok
test_write_file (testing.utils.test_fileio.test_fileio) ... ok
test_get_hwaddr (testing.utils.test_netdev.test_netdev) ... ok
test_get_ip (testing.utils.test_netdev.test_netdev) ... ok
test_get_netmask (testing.utils.test_netdev.test_netdev) ... ok
test_set_datetime (testing.utils.test_syncdatetime.test_syncdatetime) ... ok
test_cast (testing.utils.test_tools.test_tools) ... ok
test_get_image (testing.testdetection.test_CameraGuardian.test_CameraGuardian) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 23 tests in 0.003s
```

Comment: @Matt: Can you provide the output from `nosetests -vv --collect-only` so that we can see a verbose output from nose's test discovery algorithm?

Comment: I have a similar issue and I get skipped, because the test is executable..?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From [*Python Testing: Beginner's Guide*](http://www.packtpub.com/python-testing-beginners-guide/book) by Daniel Arbuckle:

> Nose looks for tests in directories and modules whose names start with `test` and `Test`, or contain a `'_'`, `'.'`, or `'-`' followed by `test` or `Test`. That's the default, but it's not actually the whole story.

[*An Extended Introduction to the nose Unit Testing Framework*](http://ivory.idyll.org/articles/nose-intro.html) shows that you can see a verbose output from nose's test discovery algorithm by running:

```
nosetests -vv --collect-only
```

When I ran the above on a directory, I noticed that Nose skips executable files. If that's your problem, you'll need to change the file mode to non-executable. On Mac OS X or Linux, this can be accomplished with:

```
chmod 644 file.py
```

or similar.

If you know that your modules/files are import-safe, then you can run Nose with the `--exe` option to "look for tests in python modules that are executable" (from `man nosetests):

```
nosetests --exe
```

Comment: I tried renaming the directories but it still is not collecting tests from them. I've tried the form test* and test_* and neither worked. I also ran it with --collect-only and it listed files from the subdirectory which were executable and, thus, skipped. But I removed the path to python.exe and the files are still listed as executable.

Comment: Try changing the file mode to non-executable for the files that Nose skipped.

Comment: The chmod trick worked. It's now collecting all tests form the working directory and all sub-directories. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 15):

You can use `--exe` in the command line to force nose to consider executables files as valid tests. If you get tired of writting `--exe` everytime, you can put the line:

> exe = True

in a .noserc (for unix/linux) or nose.cfg (for windows) file at yout home directory.