# What should a Python project structure look like for Travis CI to find and run tests?

Tags: python, travis-ci, nose, tox

I currently have a project with the following `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: python
install: "pip install tox"
script: "tox"
```

Locally, `tox` properly executes and runs 35 tests, but on Travis CI, it runs **0 tests**.

More details: https://travis-ci.org/neverendingqs/pyiterable/builds/78954867

I also tried other ways, including:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.6"
  - "2.7"
  - "3.2"
  - "3.3"
  - "3.4"
  - "3.5.0b3"
  - "3.5-dev"
  - "nightly"
# also fails with just `nosetest` and no `install` step
install: "pip install coverage unittest2"
script: "nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=pyiterable"
```

They also could not find [any tests](https://travis-ci.org/neverendingqs/pyiterable/builds/78954591).

My project structure is [Like This](https://github.com/neverendingqs/pyiterable):

```
- ...
- <module>
- tests (for the module)
- ...
```

Are the project/folders structured incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the tests location in the nosetest command? I only use Travis CI in one of my projects and I use `nosetest tests/` to run the tests. Try adjusting your tox.ini to `nosetests tests/ --with-coverage --cover-package=pyiterable`

Comment: Just tried it - no success =[

Comment: @bnlucas could I see your repo structure?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Should have added it. https://github.com/bnlucas/python-basehash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the folder structure.

It looks like the files on Travis CI are considered executable (logs from https://travis-ci.org/neverendingqs/pyiterable/builds/79049179):

```
nosetests --verbosity=3
nose.config: INFO: Ignoring files matching ['^\\.', '^_', '^setup\\.py$']
nose.selector: INFO: /home/travis/build/neverendingqs/pyiterable/LICENSE.txt is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/travis/build/neverendingqs/pyiterable/pyiterable/iterable.py is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/travis/build/neverendingqs/pyiterable/readme.md is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/travis/build/neverendingqs/pyiterable/setup.cfg is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/travis/build/neverendingqs/pyiterable/tox.ini is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /home/travis/build/neverendingqs/pyiterable/tests/test_iterable.py is executable; skipped
```

I changed `tox.ini` to run `nosetests` with `--exe` (`nosetests --exe --with-coverage --cover-package=pyiterable`), based on [Run all Tests in Directory Using Nose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333495/run-all-tests-in-directory-using-nose). After fixing some non-related errors, I was able to get the tests to run @ https://travis-ci.org/neverendingqs/pyiterable/builds/79049983!

Comment: To clarify - it's not that TravisCI *thinks* they're executable - they **are** executable, at least according to the current GitHub repo (navigate to any file, eg [iterable.py](https://github.com/neverendingqs/pyiterable/blob/master/pyiterable/iterable.py) and see at the top that it says 'executable'). Sometimes executable files are the right call, but I don't think it'll execute without a shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env python` or similar) - so I'd guess you either want both (shebang and executable permissions) or neither.

Comment: My comment not withstanding, when you do need executable Python files, the `--exe` tag is the way to go - good find!