# Unit test cases in Django not executed

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I've my Django project's unit test set up. Strangely, regardless of how many I run the command still the test cases didn't get executed. The resulting test always shows ZERO.

I suspect is the files/directories permissions issue.
Your help and advice are much appreciated.
Please see the screenshots below.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: Can you show a sample test and how you run the test?

Comment: @bdbd- pics edited.

Comment: @bdbd - I found this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867892/nose-doesnt-find-django-tests.
It could be due to the Executable flag. Please advise.

Comment: delete the test.py file in your app and run the tests again

Comment: @mrblu- Same issue. No luck!

Comment: This link below solved my problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333495/run-all-tests-in-directory-using-nose/6334161#6334161

Comment: I found this link and it solved my problem.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867892/nose-doesnt-find-django-tests)