# How to make nosetests use nosetests-2.7.exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, nose, nosetests

I'm trying to start nosetests in programmatic way from my script

**import nose
nose.main()**

or

**import nose
result = nose.run()**

and it doesn't recognize my tests , when I use :

**import subprocess
subprocess.call('c:\somePath\nosetests-2.7.exe -w C:\MyProject -v -s ')**

it works , my question is can I config somewhere nose.run() or nose.main() to use nosetests-2.7.exe

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the issue is with the wrong nosetests binary? What happens if you try

```
nose.run(argv="-w C:\MyProject -v -s".split())
```

and what error are you currently getting?

Comment: it runs , but it not recognize my tests , i made some experiments and what i found is if i use subprocess.call('c:\somePath\nosetests.exe -w C:\MyProject -v -s ') it doesnt recognize them , and if i use subprocess.call('c:\somePath\nosetests-2.7.exe -w C:\MyProject -v -s ') it works fine , i want the same result via programmatic way , i guess i should config somehow nosetests to use nosetests-2.7.exe

Comment: From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457104/nose-unable-to-find-tests-in-ubuntu), what happens if you run `nose.run(argv="-vv --collect-only".split())`?

Comment: And what happens if you rename `nosetests.exe` to `old_nosetests.exe` and `nosetests-2.7.exe` to `nosetests.exe` and then try `nose.run()`?

Comment: still can't find the tests

Comment: i'll try to rename them now

Comment: well if i rename them it works , but i want a less hardcore solution :)

Comment: i renamed back , and restarted PyCharm and everything works now , very weird , tnx for your help

Comment: No worries, I was stuck because [the relevant source code](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/setup.py#L32-L33) seemed to suggest that both nosetests.exe and nosetests-2.7.exe were pointing to the same function and I was considering opening an issue, but I'm glad it's decided to work now. Very strange though.

Comment: Dear @Vaibhav , i have another question for you :) how do i write the log to external file , tnx in advance

Comment: You should be able to supply any of the command line arguments in `argv`. Documentation is [here](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#extended-usage).

Comment: i read it 3 days already :) nothing about logging to file there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75584/discussion-between-vaibhav-sagar-and-dima-rudaev).

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to the `argv` is always the process itself. So try something like:

```
   import sys
   import nose

   nose.run(argv=[sys.argv[0], 'C:\MyProject', '-s', '-v'])
```