# LPTHW Exercise 47: nosetest ran 0 tests

Tags: python, ubuntu, nose

The exercise: http://cglab.ca/~morin/teaching/1405/lpthw/book/ex47.html

This is the output I am getting when I am running nosetests:

```
(lpthw) sj@sj-B85M-D3H:~/projects/ex47_top$ nosetests

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.002s

OK
```

My file structure:

```
.
├── bin
├── docs
├── ex47
│   ├── game.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── setup.py
└── tests
    ├── ex47_tests.py
    └── __init__.py

4 directories, 5 files
```

My files:
game.py: https://pastebin.com/g5K0kyV6
ex47_tests.py: https://pastebin.com/SU5Fp4z8
setup.py: https://pastebin.com/7QChm6qH

This is the output I should be getting:

```
~/projects/simplegame $ nosetests
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.007s

OK
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Update 1: I have added all the code here.
1. game.py

```
class Room(object):

    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.paths = {}

    def go(self, direction):
        return self.paths.get(direction, None)

    def add_paths(self, paths):
        self.paths.update(paths)
```

2. ex47_tests.py

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex47.game import Room


def test_room():
    gold = Room("GoldRoom",
            """This room has gold in it you can grab. There's a
           door to the north.""")
    assert_equal(gold.name, "GoldRoom")
    assert_equal(gold.paths, {})

def test_room_paths():
    center = Room("Center", "Test room in the center.")
    north = Room("North", "Test room in the north.")
    south = Room("South", "Test room in the south.")

    center.add_paths({'north': north, 'south': south})
    assert_equal(center.go('north'), north)
    assert_equal(center.go('south'), south)

def test_map():
    start = Room("Start", "You can go west and down a hole.")
    west = Room("Trees", "There are trees here, you can go east.")
    down = Room("Dungeon", "It's dark down here, you can go up.")

    start.add_paths({'west': west, 'down': down})
    west.add_paths({'east': start})
    down.add_paths({'up': start})

    assert_equal(start.go('west'), west)
    assert_equal(start.go('west').go('east'), start)
    assert_equal(start.go('down').go('up'), start)
```

3. setup.py

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'description': 'My Project',
    'author': 'My Name',
    'url': 'URL to get it at.',
    'download_url': 'Where to download it.',
    'author_email': 'My email.',
    'version': '0.1',
    'install_requires': ['nose'],
    'packages': ['ex47'],
    'scripts': [],
    'name': 'projectname'
    }

setup(**config)
```

Update 2: This works fine in Windows 10, but for some reason it's doesn't run on Ubuntu.

Comment: Please edit so relevant code is in the question instead of at an external link (so it will still help future readers if the pastebin goes down)

Comment: Does running with `-v` tell you anything?

Comment: @JETM I have added all the code here. Also, I have tried this on Windows 10, and it works. I am not sure why this doesn't work on Ubuntu.

Comment: @JETM I also tried `-v`. I got the same results.

Comment: @JETM Hey, I just read that thread and thanks a lot! I had to try `nosetests --exe` and it works. Link to the comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7410349/6073687. Thanks also about the `-v` suggestion, had to type in `-vv` to get the information.